# Batch file to restart service based on process memory

Tags: batch-file, memory, service, process, restart

I want to restart remote registry service according to the process memory.
I used wmic process `where "name=' svchost.exe' and workingsetsize >= 100000000"`
this would display me the memory but could not insert it into a if statement.

Comment: You should try and catch the value into a variable then you can use an if statement to test the value IF myValue >= maxValue ... Google is your best friend, I'd recommend getting to know one another a little bit.

Comment: Like this ?for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('wmic process get workingsetsize /value ^| find "svchost.exe"') do 

 (if /I "%%f" >= 10000000 
 ( Net start remoteregistry)
     )

Comment: Yeah that looks like the right track.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use the quotations around your variable, that will initialize it as a string and then will always return false when compared to a number.

Comment: Then if you want the script to continue running add an else statement that will have a goto a point above your for loop.

Comment: you are saying in If condition?

Comment: I feel like I am almost there but it gives out an error ) was unexpected at this time???\

Comment: Just checking but you know how the if/else statement works in batch scripting right? What is the full error it gives you?

Comment: for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('wmic process get workingsetsize /value ^| find "chrome.exe"') do 
if /I %%f >= 10000  ( Net start remoteregistry) writes out the script and says %%f was unaccepted at this time

Comment: Take /I out. /I indicates a case-insensitive string comparison whereas you are attempting to compare integers. try this: `for /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('wmic process get workingsetsize /value ^| find "chrome.exe"') DO (ECHO %%F; IF %%F >= "your number" "do work";) What does it echo %%F as?

Comment: did not work same error

Comment: What did it echo %%F as?

Comment: Can you the exact error message you receive to your question? I'm looking around and don't see anything for %%f was unaccepted at this time. Do you mean unexpected at this time?

Comment: Okay the issue is %%F's value isn't being set. Try adding Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion before the loop then reference %%F as !F! instead.

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Which is? You still haven't shown the actual error details.

Comment: for /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('wmic process get workingsetsize /value ^| find "chrome.exe"') DO %%F is unexpected at this time
 (ECHO %%F; IF !F! >= "1000" net start remoteregistry;)

Comment: This is the msg I got when I run it

Comment: Update your question with that message and your current code so we can see it in one place.

Comment: It may boil down to you having to do some more research on batch scripting before taking on this project and coming back to it but we'll see what we can figure out.